# Setting UILabel text is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, iboutlet

Here is my `.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PersonViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *personTitle;
```

And here is my `.m` file

```
@interface PersonViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleView;

@end

@implementation PersonViewController
//stuff …

-(void)setPersonTitle:(NSString *)personTitle
{
    [self.titleView setText:personTitle];// also self.titleView.text=personTitle
    [self.titleView setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"The title shoud match as %@ :: %@",personTitle,self.titleView.text);
}

-(NSString *)personTitle
{
    return self.titleView.text;
}

//… more stuff

@end
```

The logging shows that the value is `(null)` for `self.titleView.text` whereas `personTitle` prints the appropriate value.

I remember doing this same thing a number of times and it worked. Any ideas why it’s failing this time?

**update** I use storyboard to set my scenes. And I am using xcode-5 and iOS-7

**update: how I call**

The user clicks a button, leading to a push segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"enter prepare for segue.");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:the_identifier_for_person]) {
        NSLog(@"segue to person is progressing“);
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[PersonViewController class]]) {
            NSLog(@"segue to person destination is a match");

            PersonViewController *aPerson = (PersonViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            aPerson.personTitle=((MyItem*)self.allItems[indexPath.row]).title;
            NSLog(@"segue to person is done");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My thought is, there could be some ambiguity with personTitle, since it's both a property and a parameter. Could you try changing the name of one?

Comment: @EDUsta I have always done it like that. And many tutorials that I have used, including a popular course by Stanford University does it the same way. Remember the property stuff is just syntactic sugar. There is in fact no variable involved which is why I can set both the getter and the setter without calling `@synthesize` on personTitle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually call the `-(void)setPersonTitle:(NSString *)personTitle` method?

It seems that you aren't calling it correctly which would result in the title being null.

After reviewing the prepareForSeque it is clear that you are not calling the method. You are actually just changing the `@property` named personTitle.

In the viewDidLoad you should have it so that `self.titleView.text = self.personTitle;`

Comment: thanks for replying. But why would it work without `self` in NSLog and yet require self for setting the label's text?

Comment: `self.titleView` is actually nil. and I have no idea why. But that seems to be why the value cannot be set.

Comment: Can you post the code for when you actually call the setPersonTitle method?

Comment: Read the second line. My answer is that he is calling a method incorrectly resulting in the label being null.

Comment: I have added the segue that calls the method.

Comment: I fixed my answer which addresses your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you forgot to wire up your `UILabel` in the storyboard. Can you confirm that `self.titleView` is not null?

Comment: You are correct: the label is null. But it is actually wired to the best that I can tell: when I click on the bubble in the code, the label is highlighted in the storyboard.

Comment: I removed the connection, reconnected by dreading from storyboard, and it's still nil. Do you know how I might fix it?

Answer (score 1):

View controllers create their views on demand, but can spot that only via a call to `view`. When the view is loaded, your outlets will be populated.

Either call `view` to force loading or keep the string in abeyance until you get `viewDidLoad`.

(aside: prior to iOS 6, views would also be released in low-memory situations so the idiomatic thing is to store the string and populate on viewDidLoad)

Comment: thanks for helping. +1. But the answer was a bit too cryptic. So it took @WyattMufson 's answer for me to see what you meant.

Comment: That's the disadvantage of tapping things out on the way into a meeting — they're not always explained as clearly as you imagine them to be in your head... glad your problem got solved!

Answer (score 1):

Having accepted another answer, I wanted to show the pattern that I actually used to solve the problem, in case someone else comes looking. This pattern is best practice (yes, I forgot it for a long moment there).

```
#pragma mark - update UI
-(void)setPersonTitle:(NSString *)personTitle
{
    _personTitle=personTitle;
    if (self.view.window) [self updateUI];//only if I am on screen; or defer to viewWillAppear
}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self updateUI];
}
-(void)updateUI
{
    self.titleView.text=self.personTitle;
}
```

It is always important to update the ui when the data has changed, which is why I must make the call inside `setPersonTitle`. But because the IBOutlets are not yet set when I set personTitle in prepareForSegue, then I must also make the call inside `viewWillAppear`.